# Google Chrome reverting to previous bookmark arrangement

Tags: 14.04, unity, google-chrome

Whenever I rearrange my bookmarks on google chrome and close it, it doesn't save the changes.

I tried re-installing google chrome and signing out and signing in to chrome.  It worked at first for about 5 minutes then stops saving again. I will be researching this more as I post this question.

Comment: It might be obvious, but can you mention what you are doing to sort the bookmark?  When it looses your specific sort, what is it reverting to, sort by alphabet? Or a random order?  And finally, do you have any Bookmark plugins?  If so which?  And finally, are you mainly concerned about the Bookmark Toolbar?

Comment: I tried resetting my chrome setting and it doesn't reset my settings, but it did dissable all my extensions.  I renabled  my extensions then tried rearranging my bookmarks and it does seem to be saving them at the moment. Weird.  I'm going to continue testing it.

Comment: It was just reverting to the previous order that I had saved.  I would move a bookmark to a different folder or anywhere else and it would go back to the previous folder I had moved it from after closing the browser.

Comment: I'll try to duplicate the problem you described and see how to address it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reset settings in google chrome**.  Go to settings, advanced settings, reset settings and click reset settings. Close your browser and restart.  If it disables all your extensions renable them.
 **Update** Reboot if needed

Comment: I might be wrong, but that doesn't appear to specifically address the sorting issue.  Resetting to default will cause him to loose all his other preferences.  By the time he gets his preferred setting back, the might still be stuck with trying to figure out which setting is causing him to loose his bookmark sort.  **Update** I'm just noticing that this answer is from the OP.  If your sort now works, then that's my previous details are moot.